# The limit of $(1-\frac{1}{x})^y$ as $x,y \rightarrow \infty$ and $\frac{y}{x} \rightarrow z.$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I know the limit of $(1-\frac{1}{x})^y$ as $x,y \rightarrow \infty$ and $\frac{y}{x} \rightarrow  z$ is $e^{-z}$ but how do I show this? I was able to show this easily for the case with one variable (replace $y$ with $x$) via L'Hopital but I'm not sure about this rule for multiple variables.

Note: I am defining $z$ to be on the interval $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Hint: $(1-\frac1x)^y = \big( (1-\frac1x)^x \big)^{y/x}$.

Comment: Excellent! This solves it as the inside is simply $\frac{1}{e}.$